# rolling two dice and take the money

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

In a dice game, there are 9 piles of money valued from 1 to 9. The game involves rolling two dice multiple times. If the total of the dice is 10, 11, or 12, you re-roll until the total is between 1 and 9. For example, if you roll a 3+4=7, you can either take pile 3 and pile 4, or just pile 7. If two dice have the same result like 3+3=6, you can just take pile 6.If either option is not available, the game ends. The goal is to maximize the amount of money taken.

I think as for the distribution of the outcome of two dice, it has larger probability that the sum lying around 7, so maybe if the sum is near 7 I should take the split piles instead of the sum pile? Still very confused about what's the best strategy.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify this.I'll make some clarification.

Comment: already edited.

Comment: If you roll $~a,b ~: a \neq b,~$ then you need either $~(a+b)~$ to not yet be taken, or **both** $~a~$ and $~b~$ to not yet be taken.  This makes analysis of (for example) the $~(3,4)~$ roll tricky.

Comment: If I roll $3+4$, and only $3$ has already been taken, can I still take $4$?

Comment: When you say "if either option is not available...", do you mean "if neither option is available..." ?  [To me, the first means that both options need to be available to make a move; whereas, the second means as long as at least one option is available, you can make a move.]

Comment: @paw88789 it should be the former interpretation

Answer (score 0):

So, let's look at the space: there are 30 possible combinations we can land on in this game (6 combinations lead to re-rolls, so they can be excluded). The probability that we can choose any given pile is equal to the every result that include that pile as a face, as well as *any other* roll that equals that face (other than doubles). That leads to the following table of probabilities (note that these probabilities do not equal one, because of the significant overlap) (**edit:** Went and double-checked my work, apparently deducted a few in the wrong place):

```
|Pile|P(Pile)|
|----|-------|
|1   |10/30  |
|2   |11/30  |
|3   |12/30  |
|4   |11/30  |
|5   |12/30  |
|6   |11/30  |
|7   | 6/30  |
|8   | 5/30  |
|9   | 4/30  |
```

I believe that the most reasonable strategy would be to always pick up the available pile(s) with the least probability of appearing again - in theory this should give you the best opportunity to collect as many as possible, making it least likely to be in a situation where no pile is available. So, the priority order would be 9,8,7,1,{6,4,2},{5,3}.

(**edit**: Because I've redone the work, for those who wish to look a bit further into the distribution, here's the full list:

```
|d1|d2|sum|Piles Offered|
|--|--|---|-------------|
|1 |1 |2  |2            |
|1 |2 |3  |{1, 2}, 3    |
|1 |3 |4  |{1, 3}, 4    |
|1 |4 |5  |{1, 4}, 5    |
|1 |5 |6  |{1, 5}, 6    |
|1 |6 |7  |{1, 6}, 7    |
|2 |1 |3  |{1, 2}, 3    |
|2 |2 |4  |4            |
|2 |3 |5  |{2, 3}, 5    |
|2 |4 |6  |{2, 4}, 6    |
|2 |5 |7  |{2, 5}, 7    |
|2 |6 |8  |{2, 6}, 8    |
|3 |1 |4  |{1, 3}, 4    |
|3 |2 |5  |{2, 3}, 5    |
|3 |3 |6  |6            |
|3 |4 |7  |{3, 4}, 7    |
|3 |5 |8  |{3, 5}, 8    |
|3 |6 |9  |{3, 6}, 9    |
|4 |1 |5  |{1, 4}, 5    |
|4 |2 |6  |{2, 4}, 6    |
|4 |3 |7  |{3, 4}, 7    |
|4 |4 |8  |8            |
|4 |5 |9  |{4, 5}, 9    |
|5 |1 |6  |{1, 5}, 6    |
|5 |2 |7  |{2, 5}, 7    |
|5 |3 |8  |{3, 5}, 8    |
|5 |4 |9  |{4, 5}, 9    |
|6 |1 |7  |{1, 6}, 7    |
|6 |2 |8  |{2, 6}, 8    |
|6 |3 |9  |{3, 6}, 9    |
```

Comment: "I believe that the most reasonable strategy would be to always pick up the available pile(s) with the least probability of appearing again" : personally, I would consider balancing this priority with the priority of trying to ensure that the higher numbers (i.e. points) are *captured*.  However, from your chart, it seems that the two priorities **coincide**.  So, even if you agree with me, taking your math at face value, there doesn't seem to be a conflict.